# How to check if my Android release.keystore is correct?

Tags: android

I received a release.keystore from the developer that was working previously on the project. 
I created a custom debug.keystore based on release.keystore to test the app.
Some of the functionality of the app is broken comparing to the app on the Google Play which makes me think I might not have a valid key. For example Maps don't display correctly (gray square).

Is there a way to find out if I have a right key, that the previous app was uploaded with?
thank you!

Comment: Install the app from Play Store and try install over your new app. If you got an error, it means the certificate is wrong (assuming your are doing all other stuff right).

Comment: I just did it. Application was installed without problems, but the maps stopped working.

Answer (score 2):

don't create a debug key from it. Just sign the app with the regular key and then test it.

I believe that the maps API is tied to your release key so it will not work in your app unless you sign with your release key

Comment: That's what I did at first.
I exported the app using release.keystore and installed it on the device. Maps didn't work.

Comment: try what rciovati stated. Install the app from the market, and then try installing the copy that you signed over top of it. If the install fails then your keys are different.

Comment: I just did it. Application was installed without problems, but the maps stopped working.

Comment: Double check the map API key you are using is the correct one for the release keystore.

Comment: How can I do it? I am using Google Maps API v1.